# Creating Nested Batches in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to all of this, and I am trying to create an API script to import our users into a new CRM. I have been using Rails for about.... 48 hours.

Here is what I am trying to do, I am trying to import a few million users by using an API endpoint that allows me to create 100 users per API call, with 400 requests allowed per minute. I found the in_batches method and I am pretty sure I am on the right track, but trying to determine how to nest these into one another to ensure I can get through all of the users needed.

If there is an external source I can review to learn I would enjoy that so I can really learn this stuff more, though any suggestions or code improvements are certainly welcome. I appreciate you all.

Here is what I have so far - I excluded some of the header stuff since it has some sensitive information.

```
batch_size = 100

test_users = User.order(id: :asc).limit(400)

users = [] 

test_users.in_batches(of: batch_size) do |batch| batch.each do |user| 
    first_name = user.first_name.present? ? user.first_name : ""
    last_name = user.last_name.present? ? user.last_name : ""
    stripe_cust_id = user.subscriber&.ext_subscriber_uid.presence || ""

        user_object = {
            "name": first_name + " " + last_name, 
            "email": user.email,
            "user_fields": {
                "admin_id": user.id,
                "membership_tier": user.subscription_tier,
                "stripe_id": stripe_cust_id,
                "trialed": user.trialed? ? "true" : "false",
                "user_uuid": user.uuid
            }
        }

        users << user_object 

    end



    HTTParty.post(uri, body: "{\"users\": " + users.to_json + "}", headers: headers)

    users.clear

end
```

UPDATED NOTE:: Would it be something as simple as this?

```
batch_size_outer = 1000  (<--- or any size I want)
batch_size_inner = 100

test_users = User.order(id: :asc).limit(400)

users = []

test_users.in_batches(of: batch_size_outer) do |outer_batch|
  outer_batch.in_batches(of: batch_size_inner) do |inner_batch|
    inner_batch.each do |user|
```

My understanding is that after the batching is sorted out I will need to also then use Typhoeus to run some parallel API calls, but I have not gotten to that point yet.